# Why does math.random(999999999999) returns 1 in Lua?

Tags: math, random, lua

I just tried: `print(math.random(999999999999))` and it has printed `1`.

Also any `math.random()` that includes `999999999999` is printing the same thing. Some examples:

`print(math.random(1.999999999999))` » `1`

`print(math.random(1999999999999))` » `1`

```
for k,v in next,{math.random(999999999999), math.random(1999999999999), math.random(2.999999999999)} do
    print(v)
end
```

» `1`

```
local n = math.random(999999999999)
print(n==1)
```

» `true`

Then I think you understood (if you know Lua of course). Can you explain me?

**@Edits:**

The Lua version I'm using is 5.2.

I also tried `print(math.random(-999999999999))` and it printed `111711452`. It looks like it worked as a positive number.

Comment: `print(math.random(999999999999))` works fine for me in the [Lua online demo](https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo). Which version of Lua are you using?

Comment: the version is 5.2

Comment: It works fine for me with Lua 5.2 as well in both Linux and Mac OS X.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Windows 8.1 OS. I've tried that script on Transformice game, which uses Lua 5.2. Then maybe the problem should be on the game API and/or on the Lua version as you've mentioned in your answer?

Comment: Maybe!I used Lua on windows 10 and faced the same problem Then I finally fixed it.But the explanation of the problem is the same as I mentioned as it is wrapping up the overflown value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is surely because `math.random` treats the input arguments passed in Lua 5.1 and/or 5.2. From `[mathlib.c]` [**1**](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lmathlib.c.html#math_random):

As you may know in `C`, a standard int can represent values `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`. Adding `+1` to `2,147,483,647`, like in your use-case, will overflow and wrap around the value giving  `-2,147,483,648`. The end result is negative since you're multiplying a positive with a negative number.

There are a few ways to rectify and handle this problem:

1. Upgrade to latest Lua version 5.3 . That one has since fixed this issue by treating the input arguments as lua_Number instead.
2. Switch to LuaJIT which does not have this integer overflow issue.
3. Patch the Lua 5.1 and/or 5.2 source yourself with the fix and recompile.
4. Modify your random range so it does not overflow

And for your last query read the [**documentation**](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial)

Notice the last line quotes:

> `math.random(upper)` generates integer numbers between ***1 and
>   upper***.upper and lower must be integer. In other case Lua casts
>   upper into an integer, sometimes giving `math.floor(upper)` and others
>   `math.ceil(upper)`, with **unexpected results** (the same for lower).

Comment: It works fine for me with Lua 5.2 in both Linux and Mac OS X.